# Scroll to top of WKInterfaceTable in WatchKit?

Tags: ios, swift, watchkit, apple-watch, wkinterfacetable

I have a `WKInterfaceTable` in my storyboard. When a row is tapped, I make changes to the record display but would like to scroll to the top. How do I do this?

This is what my code looks like so far:

```
@IBOutlet var currentTable: WKInterfaceTable!

override func table(table: WKInterfaceTable, didSelectRowAtIndex rowIndex: Int) {
    // Make changes to records...

    // TODO: Scroll to the top???
}
```

I couldn't find anything in the API for the table `currentTable` unless there's something I'm missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I wonder how you have overseen this simple solution in the docs?!

This should do the trick:

```
override func table(table: WKInterfaceTable, didSelectRowAtIndex rowIndex: Int) 
{
    // Make changes to records...

    table.scrollToRowAtIndex(0)
}
```

Also your outlet seems to be wrong. If you create them with IB, it will automatically mark them as 'weak'.

Hope this will help you :)

Answer (score 2):

In the docs for `WKInterfaceTable`, you'll find a helpful method called `scrollToRowAtIndex`. Simply provide the index for the first row.

https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/WatchKit/Reference/WKInterfaceTable_class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/WKInterfaceTable/scrollToRowAtIndex: